# Powershell and MailKit - Fails in Script

Tags: powershell, mailkit, mimekit

I'm attempting to use the new MailKit / Mimekit instead of Send-MailMessage in Powershell. I found Send-[MailKitMessage](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Send-MailKitMessage/1.0.1/Content/Send-MailKitMessage.psm1) 1.0.1 on the Powershell Gallery

My needs are simple and the Powershell will be used for internal alerts only, so I simplified the code to suit my needs.

```
    ***using namespace MailKit
       using namespace MimeKit
    
         $emailDLL = "F:\Apps\Email\MailKit.dll"
         $mimeDll = "F:\Apps\Email\MimeKit.dll"
         Add-Type -Path $emailDLL
         [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($mimeDll)
```

#extend classes to be available to the calling script (MimeKit assembly is loaded first from the manifest file so is available when this module loads)
class MailboxAddressExtended : MailboxAddress { #does not allow parameterless construction
MailboxAddressExtended([string]$Name, [string]$Address ) : base($Name, $Address) {
[string]$Name,      #can be null
[string]$Address    #cannot be null
}
}

```
        class InternetAddressListExtended : InternetAddressList {}
        $List = New-Object InternetAddressListExtended # of type MimeKit.InternetAddress
    
         $smtpClient = New-Object MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient
     
         $message = [MimeKit.MimeMessage]::new()
         $TextPart = [MimeKit.TextPart]::new("html")
    
     #endregion
    
     [string[]]$recipients = "email@testdomain.com".Split(',').Trim()
     $from = "Dev_Test@testdomain.com"
     $smtpSvr = '190.132.148.22'
     $smtpPort = 25

function sendEmail ($subjectline,$msgbody) {
    $message.From.Add($from)  
    foreach ($address in $recipients) {$List.Add($address)}
    $message.To.AddRange($List)
    $TextPart.Text = $msgbody
    $message.Body = $TextPart
    $message.Subject = $subjectline
    
    if(!$smtpClient.IsConnected) {
    $smtpClient.Connect($smtpSvr)
    }
    if ($smtpClient.IsConnected) {
        $smtpClient.Send($message)
        $smtpClient.Disconnect($true)
        
    }***

 }
```

When I run the above code in a PS1 script, I get an error:

> Unable to find type [MailboxAddress]

I can manually enter the same code in a Powershell window and it works as expected.
I have used PS5 v5.1, PS7 v7.1 and I get the same error.
I went with the above code since it allowed me to send emails to more than one individual / group.
While relatively new to Powershell, I was able to work through all the previous issues to come up with the above code.

I greatly appreciate any guidance that can be provided.

Answer (score 2):

1. `Send-MailKitMessage` is a comlete module that should be installed. Follow [here](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Send-MailKitMessage/3.1.0)
2. Types like `[MailboxAddress]` ( `[MimeKit.MailboxAddress]` ) are expected to be load from DLL files, but if you use only `PSM1` file, there are no DLLs to load this from.
3. It's 3.1.0 version currently *(as for 2021-03-04)*
4. It (*v3.1.0*) works only on **PowerShell 7+**, because it uses [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com//powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#ternary-operator--if-true--if-false) whick was introduced is PSv7. I think it can be easily fixed to port back to PSv5, but this requires testing.
5. If you don't want to install module, download `nupkg` file, unzip it using `7zip` and try using like this:

---

```
Import-Module -Name 'C:\...\send-mailkitmessage.3.1.0\Send-MailKitMessage.psd1'
```

or like this:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile('C:\...\send-mailkitmessage.3.1.0\Libraries\BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll')
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile('C:\...\send-mailkitmessage.3.1.0\Libraries\MailKit.dll')
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile('C:\...\send-mailkitmessage.3.1.0\Libraries\MimeKit.dll')
Import-Module -Name 'C:\...\send-mailkitmessage.3.1.0\Send-MailKitMessage.psm1'
```

Comment: I download the latest Send-MailKitMessage, manually loaded the files per the recommendations. I then created the needed variables & Parameter struct and loaded into window. I was able to send-MailkitMessage  Parameters successfully. I put the same commands into PS1 file, minus send-MailkitMessage  Parameters and it launches okay. But when I run send-MailkitMessage Parameters in window it can't see $HTMLBody, all variable parameters are in the PS1 file. Prior to running Send, I can see the info in variables, after Send they are empty. FYI: I omitted the AT sign in mod signature

Answer (score 1):

Although I made some progress attempting to incorporate Send-MailkitMessage, I continued to encounter unexpected errors. I decided to go back to basics since my needs were basics and I was sending out internal Alerts emails only. I created this test PS1 file:

````
using namespace MailKit 
using namespace MimeKit

     $emailDLL = "F:\Apps\Email\MailKit.dll"
     $mimeDll = "F:\Apps\Email\MimeKit.dll"
     Add-Type -Path $emailDLL
        
     [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($mimeDll)
     [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($emailDLL)

        class MailboxAddressExtended : MailboxAddress { #does not allow parameterless construction
        MailboxAddressExtended([string]$Name, [string]$Address ) : base($Name, $Address) {
            [string]$Name,      #can be null
            [string]$Address    #cannot be null
        }
    } 

    class InternetAddressListExtended : InternetAddressList {}
    $List = New-Object InternetAddressListExtended # of type MimeKit.InternetAddress

     $message = [MimeKit.MimeMessage]::new()
     $TextPart = [MimeKit.TextPart]::new("html")

     [string[]]$recipients = "name@company.net".Split(',').Trim()
     $from = "Dev_Mailkit@company.net"
     $smtpSvr = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
     $smtpPort = 25

     $message.From.Add($from)  
       foreach ($address in $recipients) {$List.Add($address)}
       $message.To.AddRange($List)

        $smtpClient = New-Object MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient

      $TextPart.Text = "Mailkit Test 30000"
      $message.Body = $TextPart
      $message.Subject = "Another Test" 

      if(!$smtpClient.IsConnected) {
    $smtpClient.Connect($smtpSvr)
    }
    if ($smtpClient.IsConnected) {
        $smtpClient.Send($message)
        $smtpClient.Disconnect($true)
        
    }```

@filimonic  I greatly appreciate the feedback, which is how I was able to overcome my initial obstacles.
````