# Load PowerShell Assembly before using their Command

Tags: powershell, .net-assembly, mailkit

I am trying to send an email via `Send-MailKitMessage`, however, I therefore need to create a from and a receipient list as mailkit types. How can I create these types before calling the command? It throws me an error if I do not call `Send-MailKitMessage` beforehand.

```
$RecipientList = [MimeKit.InternetAddressList]::new()
$RecipientList.Add([MimeKit.MailboxAddress]::new("me", "me@example.com"))
Send-MailKitMessage -SMTPServer $SMTPServer -Port $SMTPPort `
  -Credential $SMTPCredential -UseSecureConnectionIfAvailable `
  -From [MimeKit.MailboxAddress]::new("me", "me@example.com") `
  -RecipientList $RecipientList `
  -Subject "Test" `
  -HTMLBody "Body"
```

Error:

```
PS C:\Users\example> [MimeKit.InternetAddressList]::new()
InvalidOperation: Unable to find type [MimeKit.InternetAddressList].
```

Comment: Could [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66465409/9898643) be of help?

Comment: `Import-Module Send-MailKitMessage`

Comment: `Add-Type -AssemblyName MimeKit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load the assembly before you can reference any of the types in it.

The easiest way to load the assembly is to load a module that references the assembly. You can use either `Import-Module Send-MailKitMessage` before referencing the type or, if you're calling a script file, `#requires -Modules Send-MailKitMessage` at any point in the script file.